# Compiling a solution with MonoDevelop or Cake/XBuild giving different results

Tags: mono, monodevelop, xbuild, cakebuild

I'm getting a different behavior when compiling a solution with **MonoDevelop 5.1.0** and the same solution through a [Cake](http://cakebuild.net/) script invoking [XBuild](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/xbuild/).

When compiling the solution with MonoDevelop, everything works fine.
When compiling through my cake script, I get the following error:

> The type System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced.  Consider adding a reference to assembly System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

**What could be the reason for such a different behavior?**

The cake script doesn't do anything fancy. It just calls XBuild with the exact same solution.

**My environment (on Fedora 23):**

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.0 (Stable 4.4.0.142/81f38a9 Thu Apr 28 09:14:25 EDT 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen

XBuild Version:
XBuild Engine Version 14.0
Mono, Version 4.4.0.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors
```

Comment: can you test your xbuild command directly so that you can remove `Cake` from the equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to instead of using the XBuild aliases to use the [Cake.Xamarin](https://github.com/Redth/Cake.Xamarin) addin which provides the [MDToolBuild](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.xamarin/c86482e2/75b96db2) alias for the [mdtool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mdtool.1.html) which uses Monodevelop without GUI to compile your solution.

```
public static void MDToolBuild(
       FilePath projectOrSolutionFile,
       Action<MDToolSettings> settings
)
```

Example usage in a Cake script:

```
#addin "Cake.Xamarin"

MDToolBuild(
   "./mySolution.sln",
   settings=> { settings.Configuration = "Debug"; },
);
```

Comment: Your workaround works perfectly. A zillion thanks. Still, I would be interested to know why I have such a behavior with XBuild.